# Keeping Track of JWT in a permanent storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I have an authentication service in Spring Boot which issues/validates JWT. The user passes in username/password, the service validates it, and returns access token and refresh token in response. Here are some of the things I want in this service:

1. I want to make sure that the user can use the same refresh token only once to get a new access token, and make sure the refresh token is expired after getting used.
2. I want to clean up expired access & refresh tokens after they get expired. To do this, I need a storage to keeping track of all JWT tokens I issued and the expiration date.

Would this be recommended? If so, what would be the storage that fits the best in this case? Im looking at AWS Key Management Service, but not sure if there is a better option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Key Management Service is completely ill-suited for this. You simply cannot use this service for that, there is no real consideration to make here, the service is does something completely different. The only way KMS might be used here is to *sign* and verify the JWTs.

What you want to use is DynamoDB and store the Refresh tokens there. If a user uses a refresh token you check the DynamoDB for the token, remove it, act on it and maybe issue and save a new one. You *can* maybe add a TTL on the tokens to have automatic removal of expired tokens but you cannot *rely* on that TTL to work.

JWTs have an expiration built-in and they are expired if that expiration date is reached. They should not be stored anywhere in the backend.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll definitely use DynamoDB for this. I was thinking of storing the issued JWT in a storage somewhere (maybe DynamoDB if possible), but I guess it is not a good practice to do it? I just want to clear out all expired tokens (access tokens, refresh tokens) periodically.

Comment: @louprogramming You do not need to clear them out manually if you set a TTL on the stored tokens.

Comment: I see. I have expiration date already set for each token (for both access and refresh). I guess this is enough generally?

Comment: @louprogramming yes, if it is in the proper format you can just set the TTL flag for it in the dynamodb: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html - otherwise you can add a second column with the same value logically but in ttl-compliant format.

Comment: Thanks! I was talking to one of my team members about it and it was suggested we would want to associate JWT with each particular user so that when we refresh token, we want to simply update that row with specific user info instead of creating a new row for every refresh tokens. Would it make sense to use permanent storage in this case? or is it still not applicable?

Comment: @louprogramming you can do that, yes. I would probably not do it but I you may have your business reasons for it.